# Pferdeäpfel von Eseln

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology

In Tucholskys Pyrenäenbuch steht der Satz

> Aber wenn er an *Pferdeäpfel von Eseln* kam, stand er still, beroch die Sache ausführlich … dann hob er den Kopf in die Luft und lachte.
>
> <sub>(Kurt Tucholsky (1927): *Von Barèges bis Arreau*. In: Ein Pyrenäenbuch. Text online bei [Zeno.org](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Tucholsky,+Kurt/Werke/1927/Ein+Pyren%C3%A4enbuch/Von+Bar%C3%A8ges+bis+Arreau))</sub>

Nun wundere ich mich, dass man auch bei *Eseln* von *Pferdeäpfeln* spricht. Allerdings habe ich nichts über *Esel(s)äpfel* gefunden. Ist *Pferdeäpfel* tatsächlich der geläufige Ausdruck bei Eseln? Und vielleicht auch bei Zebras?

Comment: Ein Pferdeapfel der Zwietracht? Ich gönne mir erst einmal einen [Crottin de Chavignol](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crottin_de_Chavignol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nachdem alle Esel und alle Zebras zur Gattung der Pferde gehören, ist ja nichts falsch daran, die Ausscheidungen von Eseln und Zebras als Pferdeäpfel zu bezeichnen. Eine Art, die »Pferd« heißt, gibt es gar nicht, sondern nur eine Gattung mit diesem Namen und eine Hierarchiestufe darüber die Familie der Pferde, zu der aber nur eine einzige Gattung gehört. (Andere Gattungen unterhalb der Familie der Pferde sind schon lange ausgestorben.)

Die Gattung der Pferde wird in caballine und nichtcaballine Pferde unterteilt.

Zu den caballinen Pferden gehören diese beiden Arten:

- **Hauspferd** Davon gibt es viele unterschiedliche Rassen, die als Nutztiere gehalten werden (um darauf zu reiten, als Arbeitstiere, und um sie zu essen)
- **Przewalski-Pferd** (Asiatisches Wildpferd)

Zu den nichtcaballinen Pferden gehören diese 6 (oder 7) Arten:

- **Afrikanischer Esel**
- **Asiatischer Esel** (Ob Onager eine eigene Art sind oder zu den Asiatischen Eseln gehören ist umstritten)
- **Kiang** (auch bekannt als Tibet-Wildesel)
- **Bergzebra**
- **Steppenzebra**
- **Grevyzebra**

Und weil alle diese Tiere Pferde sind, lassen alle von ihnen Pferdeäpfel fallen.

---

### BELEGE

- Einen Beleg dafür, dass das tatsächlich so gehandhabt wird, hat ja bereits der Fragesteller geliefert: [Kurt Tucholsky: Ein Pyrenäenbuch](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Tucholsky,+Kurt/Werke/1927/Ein+Pyren%C3%A4enbuch/Von+Bar%C3%A8ges+bis+Arreau)
- In der Schweizer Tageszeitung Tagblatt wurde in einem Artikel gebeten: [Pferdeäpfel bitte zusammenkehren](https://www.tagblatt.ch/ostschweiz/frauenfeld-munchwilen/pferdeaepfel-bitte-zusammenkehren-ld.910041) und im letzten Absatz wurden auch explizit die Verursacher der Pferdeäpfel genannt:

  > Laut Thurgauer Landwirtschaftsamt leben in der Gemeinde derzeit 101 Tiere der Pferdegattung (Pferde, Ponies, **Esel**)
- In dem Blog [Tödliche Gefahr durch gefressene Pferdeäpfel!](https://www.tierarzt-facharani.de/toedliche-gefahr-durch-gefressene-pferdeaepfel/) eines Tierarztes wird vor der tödlichen Gefahr für Hunde gewarnt, die von giftigen Pferdeäpfeln ausgeht, und im ersten Satz werden die Verursacher dieser Ausscheidungen genannt:

  > In der Herbst-/Wintersaison werden Pferde und **Esel** oftmals mit dem Wirkstoff Ivamectin entwurmt.
- Noch klarer wird es im Hamburger Abendblatt im Artikel [Auf Gut Stegen gehört auch Abäppeln zu den Tagenaufgaben](https://www.abendblatt.de/region/stormarn/article108044095/Auf-Gut-Stegen-gehoert-auch-Abaeppeln-zu-den-Tagesaufgaben.html) ausgedrückt:

  > "Abäppeln", erklärt Antje Dirsus, 48, "so nennen wir das Aufsammeln der Pferdeäpfel auf der **Esel-** und Pferdekoppel."
- In dem Artikel [Pferde - Eselleben](https://www.hof-amalion.de/pferde-eselleben) ist neben Pferden auch viel von Eseln die Rede, und wenn dann die Rede auf den Dung kommt, wird nur das Wort Pferdeäpfel verwendet:

  > Für uns ist es ein Anliegen, über die Tiere auch einen Zugang zu den natürlichen Kreisläufen zu haben:
  > Wenn wir Kopfweiden schneiden und die **Esel** die dicken Stämme entrinden, dann trocknet das Holz schneller und wir können es eher als Brennholz nutzen. Die dünneren Äste werden als Haufen aufgeschichtet und sind wunderbare Rückzugsräume und Nistplätze für Amseln und Zaunkönige, sowie für Eidechsen.
  > Um den Stall und die Raufen sammeln wir die **Pferdeäpfel** auf. Der Mist wird aufgeschichtet und von Kompostwürmern und Effektiven Mikroorganismen zu wunderbarem Dünger verwandelt. Der wiederum kommt den jungen Obstbäumen und den starkzehrenden Gemüsepflanzen, Rosen und Stauden sehr zu Gute.
- Auf einer weiteren [Seite im Internet](https://portal.wurmbekampfung.eu/de/produkt/1421) steht:

  > Geeignet für:
  > Pferde, **Esel,** Maultiere und Maulesel
  > ...
  > Nehmen Sie für den Test 3 bis 4 größere **Pferdeäpfel** (oder 5 bis 6 bei kleinen Ponys), die nicht mit dem Boden in Berührung gekommen sind.

Comment: Und wie ist das bei "Tannenzapfen", die in den meisten Fällen eigentlich Fichtenzapfen sind (wobei Fichten taxonomisch nicht zu den Tannen gehören). Oder noch schlimmer: was ist mit dem "Zug", bei dem die Lok hinten ist und die Waggons schiebt und nicht zieht?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich weiß schon, *was* ich Curd antworten würde, aber das passt nicht in meine Antwort (das wäre dann eine Themenverfehlung) und in die Kommentare schon gar nicht. Und wich weiß nicht, ob dir das aufgefallen ist, aber du musstest 6 Kommentarboxen verwenden um deinen Gedanken auszuformulieren, ich würde mindestens denselben Platz benötigen, und dafür sind Kommentare nun mal nicht da. Und zum Chat: Ich chatte nicht, ich mag dieses Format nicht. Ich möchte Fragen beantworten.

Comment: Ich denke, dann müssen wir einfach mit dem Dissens leben. :)

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort sehr lehrreich. Bezüglich Pferden habe ich offenbar eine große Bildungslücke. Auch wenn ich kürzere Antworten, wie die von @Raffzahn, eher schätze, werde diese Antwort akzeptieren, da sie die erste ist und weil sie interessante und relevante Belege liefert.

Answer (score 6):

Ja, ist der umgangssprachliche Begriff für alle (eher festen) Hinterlassenschaften von Pferden, Esel, Ponys, Mulis - eigentlich allem was zur Pferdefamilie ([Equidae](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidae)) gehört. Also zumindest zu Zeiten als Lasttiere noch ganz normal waren auf der Straße. Damit eigentlich auch bei Zebras, in der Praxis begegneten Menschen Zebras im Alltagsleben aber eher selten.

Das Verb dazu heißt [`äpfeln`](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A4pfeln).

Ein alternativer Begriff, eher im Süden Deutschlands zuhause, ist Rossknödel.

Comment: +1 von mir. Ich verstehe aber nicht ganz, warum deine Antwort, die ganz ohne Hintergrundinformationen und Belege daherkommt, im Wesentlichen aber genau dasselbe aussagt wie [meine Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69377/1487) plus drei Punkte (inklusive meiner Wertung) bekommt, während meine weitaus ausführlichere, aber inhaltlich gleiche Antwort mit minus 3 Punkten abgestraft wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die Wunder von SE halt :)) Im Ernst, das erleb ich laufend - wenn auch nicht gleich mit Negativ. Bewertung hat hier viel mit Erwartung zu tun. Gerade wenn es um Sprache geht, dann ist eine technische Begründung, so richtig sie ist, selten das, was die Erwartung befriedigt. Da helfen dann auch keine Fundstellen.  Dazu kommt, dass es um ein Thema geht, was im Alltag praktisch nicht mehr vertreten ist, da wird dann noch mehr nach Logik geurteilt, aber Sprache, besonders Alltagssprache, ist nie logisch sondern kurz, praktisch und auf schnelles Verständnis ausgelegt. Das verwirrt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast bei mir wars so, dass ich zu der Zeit downgevoted habe, als ich deine Antwort noch hauptsächlich als "Taxonomie sagt X => Sprache muss dem logisch folgen" interpretiert habe, was ich für falsch halte. Mittlerweile finde ich sie besser und habe den Downvote entfernt; aber vom Edit bekommt man ja nur durch Zufall was mit. Vielleicht ist es anderen ähnlich gegangen. (Relativ finde ich trotzdem diese Antwort besser, einfach weil mir die prägnanz gefällt und genügt.)

Comment: Danke für die Antwort (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Nun, im Prinzip gibt es keine Vorschrift, die einem verbieten würde, Dinge so zu nennen, wie man mag - außer den Drang, verstanden werden zu wollen (der bei einem Schriftsteller allerdings vorausgesetzt werden kann).

Eselmist als "Pferdeäpfel" zu bezeichnen, ist definitiv eher ungewöhnlich. Ich habe eine Weile gesucht (in Fachliteratur über Esel, aber auch das Internet gibt keine Fundstelle her, wo Esel im Zusammenhang mit Pferdeäpfeln genannt würden), aber keine zweite Referenz gefunden, wo dies überhaupt gemacht worden wäre. Ich finde hauptsächlich den Begriff "Eselmist", oder "Kot" oder euphemistische Umschreibungen. Betrachtet man Eselmist genauer, stellt man auch fest, dass der sich optisch von Pferdeäpfeln unterscheidet: Er ist i.A. fester, deutlicher als "Kugeln" definiert und wesentlich dunkler als typische Pferdeäpfel. Kurz und knapp: Wenn ein Pferd kackt wie ein Esel, sollte man den Tierarzt rufen.

Jetzt gibt es für Tucholskys Wortwahl zwei zwei Möglichkeiten: Entweder, er machte das mit Absicht, weil er uns etwas damit sagen will, oder aber (für jemanden wie Tucholsky möglich, aber unwahrscheinlich) er wußte es einfach nicht besser.

Anzunehmen, dass Tucholski, als er das schrieb, nicht gewusst hätte, dass Pferde und Esel zwei verschiedene Dinge sind (und demnach durchaus auch unterschiedliche Exkremente mit unterschiedlichen Bezeichnungen haben), ist unwahrscheinlich. Anzunehmen, es wäre ihm wider besseren Wissens egal ("der Leser wird schon wissen, was ich meine"), ist möglich und wäre, da der Rest des Textes mit großer "spielerischer Leichtigkeit" geschrieben ist, durchaus nicht auszuschließen.

Ich habe aber den Eindruck, dass er uns mit der Verwendung dieses Wortes etwas sagen wollte - betrachtet man das Stimmungsbild des Ich-Erzählers genauer, stellt man fest, dass er sich unsicher, aber trotzdem zuversichtlich in einem  fremden Umfeld bewegt und in einem humorigen Grundton darüber berichtet. Er macht uns klar, dass er sich mit Wegen im Gebirge, Serpentinen in einem fremden Land, und vor allem mit Eseln nun überhaupt nicht auskennt und unterstreicht es auch noch damit, dass er ihren Mist als Pferdeäpfel bezeichnet. Er schreibt auch noch, dass der Esel "lacht", als er an dem Mist schnuppert, was eine mögliche, aber  eher laienhafte Interpretation des Tierverhaltens ist.

Ich bin aus dem letzten Grund der Ansicht (ja, das ist Meinung, und ja, mir fehlt ein Beweis dafür...), dass das Wort mit voller Absicht da steht, einfach nur, um noch einmal zu unterstreichen, wie der Erzähler sich als Fremder in einer fremden Umgebung fühlt.

Comment: Zitat: »aber auch das Internet gibt keine Fundstelle her, wo Esel im Zusammenhang mit Pferdeäpfeln genannt würden« Das beweist nur, dass du nicht wirklich danach gesucht hast. Ich habe in [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69377/1487) sechs Fundstellen angeführt, wo genau das gemacht wurde, was du in Abrede stellst. In allen 6 Stellen werden die Ausscheidungen von Eseln *Pferdeäpfel* genannt.

Comment: Zitat: »... dass Pferde und Esel zwei verschiedene Dinge sind.« Genau das ist falsch! Es stimmt ganz einfach nicht. Esel **SIND** Pferde. *»Pferd«* ist der Überbegriff für Hauspferde, Esel und Zebras. Steht alles in [meiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69377/1487)